# Defining and using a key-value list of generics

Tags: typescript

I'm sure I'm missing a key concept here but here's what I'm trying to do.

These are the definitions:

```
export interface ActionError {
  message: string;
}

export interface Request<Payload> {
  payload: Payload;
}

export interface Response<Payload> {
  send: (response?: Payload) => void;
  error: (error?: ActionError) => void;
}

export interface Action<RequestPayload, ResponsePayload> {
  (request: Request<RequestPayload>, response: Response<ResponsePayload>): void;
}

export interface Actions {
  [key: string]: Action<unknown, unknown>;
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a key-value list of Actions that can work with any type that can be passed to a function like below:

```
const processActions = (actions: Actions) => {
  // Removed for brevity
};
```

Then I create a key-value object of actions:

```
const sampleActions = {
  'hello-world': async (
    request: Request<{ input: string }>,
    response: Response<{ output: number }>
  ) => {
    response.send({ output: 10 });
  },
};
```

And when I call `processActions` with `sampleActions`:

`processActions(sampleActions)` I get this error:

```
Argument of type '{ "hello-world": (request: Request<{    input: string;}>, response: Response<{    output: number;}>) => Promise<void>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Actions'.
  Property '"hello-world"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(request: Request<{    input: string;}>, response: Response<{    output: number;}>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Action<unknown, unknown>'.
      Types of parameters 'request' and 'request' are incompatible.
        Type 'Request<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Request<{ input: string; }>'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ input: string; }'
```

So what am I doing wrong and how can I make this work with any generic type parameter?

Comment: Is your `sampleActions` dictionary supposed to contain values of the same type (i.e. same `ReqPayload` and `ResPayload`), or each can be different?

Comment: @ghybs Yes, each parameter can be of a different type.

Comment: While it's not an error to shadow built-in types, it prevents you from using them, and forces consumers of your exported types to rename them during import in order to preserve the built-ins in their own environment. Please consider using unique type names for your currently shadowed types (e.g. `Error`, `Request`, `Response`, etc.).

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks for the comment. Actually, I'm not shadowing them, I just changed their names to make it clear for the people looking at the code. They have different names than I posted above :)

Comment: Add two generics to `Actions` as `Actions<Req, Res>` and set the type actions to the variable passed to the function.

Comment: @Akxe I think that will only work if every action in `sampleActions` have the same request and response payloads. This is true in the example code in the question, but OP clarified in the comments that in their real code the actions are heterogeneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the error is simply due to [function parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance). You can satisfy the compiler (and potentially infer a narrowed return type from the processing function) by using a generic for the actions parameter, constrained by a type that uses `any` for the payloads instead of `unknown`, as shown in the example below.

> Whether `any` or `unknown` is used, you still won't have information about the actual types required by the actions' payloads within the processing function. This is simply the nature of the pattern you're using.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQWxgQiQFEopo4BvAWACg44BbYAZ3cwHNgAuOOxhRk3ANyMAvo0ahIsRCjRZcBIiSQAlYAEcArhxgAeAAqYAngBsImACYA+Wo2ZgL1uwLNWbtiQ2kMsuDQ8MioGDh4hMSk2uyQSOzApm4+jvRMgsBItgIAFFAcCUkA-J6pdgCUcAC8jgBuEAi+znBoVFD57dBlajHklNDVdXCNzX4BQfKhShGq0RpG2jpe7rYANHBxq2lOmQW6BkICC7GHhku6O3b2m4XxpEkn6mcPicnbFQ6VAmMt-jIGOg9EgXkg4GAqLhOKdEnAjLD2G0QKgckjtNhoLYjEIREhuJtYUZMEhzJsSeZ7FS8jh+uxnnTqhlmAB6FlbYAsCD1YC2ODoagAI0K9QQMHMUkBmMS8C4LDAlmAiNqe2YAHIABbASzWAC0AHdoJZbGqBJh2OZQXA8q1mIV9IYGRplkdjDRFGA9DABLjRHBJLdbXB7sV+H1nUVHsl3RAvZ7vXAkHoWIK0P7A5lhukgyGowA6JI5PIxuNegQARgADP7Kn5mJJ1lI-IxIRBoexEXk5QqlWD2LW4Gy4BAANaMIA)

```ts
export interface ActionError {
  message: string;
}

export interface ActionRequest<Payload> {
  payload: Payload;
}

export interface ActionResponse<Payload> {
  send: (response?: Payload) => void;
  error: (error?: ActionError) => void;
}

export interface Action<ReqPayload, ResPayload> {
  (request: ActionRequest<ReqPayload>, response: ActionResponse<ResPayload>): void;
}

function processActions <Actions extends Record<string, Action<any, any>>>(actions: Actions) {
  // Removed for brevity
}

const sampleActions = {
  'hello-world': async (
    request: ActionRequest<{ input: string }>,
    response: ActionResponse<{ output: number }>,
  ) => {
    response.send({ output: 10 });
  },
};

processActions(sampleActions); // ok, hover in playground link to see inferred generics
```